# Substitute a value of an XML tag to another using shell

Tags: xml, shell

Below is the sample XML file. I need to substitute value of third tag (`AAA`) to fifth tag.

```
<head>
    <firsttag>
        <secondtag>
            <thirdtag>AAA</thirdtag>    
            <a><thirdtag>1111</thirdtag></a>
            <fifithtag>A123</fifthtag>    
        </secondtag>
    </firsttag>
    ...
    ...    
    <firsttag>    
        <secondtag>
            <thirdtag>AAA</thirdtag>   
            <a><thirdtag>1111</thirdtag></a>
            <fifithtag>A123</fifthtag>
        </secondtag>
    </firsttag>
</head>
```

Output should be

```
<head>
    <firsttag>
        <secondtag>
            <thirdtag>AAA</thirdtag>
            <a><thirdtag>1111</thirdtag></a>
            <fifithtag>AAA</fifthtag>
        </secondtag>
    </firsttag>
    ...
    ...
    <firsttag>
        <secondtag>
            <thirdtag>AAA</thirdtag>
            <a><thirdtag>1111</thirdtag></a>
            <fifithtag>AAA</fifthtag>
        </secondtag>
    </firsttag>
</head>
```

Comment: Which thirdtag's value?

Comment: Need to replace <fifithtag>A123</fifthtag> with <thirdtag>AAA</thirdtag>
so my output will be <fifithtag>AAA</fifthtag>
I just need to substitute the value

Comment: So is it always the first '<thirdtag>' found in the file or (something else)?  That is how do I know it is 'AAA' and not '1111'?

Comment: Its always the <thirdtag>, 
Ex- Only the thirdtag above "<secondtag>"
I will be replacing the value to fifthtag

Comment: ok so value of thirdtag which is inside secondtag to be used to replace in fifthtag right? and what do you mean by replace using shell? bash shell script right?

Comment: just made a small change to the base xml file. The <thirdtag> is the one just below the <secondtag>
Yes, i meant bash script

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've entirely understood your question, but here's an awk-script which seems like it does what you're asking for.  It's not 100% robust, for that you'd actually need something which parses the XML for real.

> awk -f this.script < inputfile > outputfile

```
$0 ~ "<secondtag>" {
    S = 1
}

$0 ~ "</secondtag>" {
    S = 0
}

$0 ~ "<thirdtag>" && S {
    B = index($0, ">")
    T = substr($0, B+1)
    E = index(T, "<")
    V = substr(T, 1, E-1)
}

$0 ~ "<fifthtag>" {
    B = index($0, ">")
    F = substr($0, 1, B)
    T = substr($0, B+1)
    E = index(T, "<")
    R = substr(T, E)
    printf "%s%s%s\n", F,V,R
    next
}

{
    print
}
```